# What would be the equivalent of R's mboost in Python?

Tags: python, r, xgboost, boosting

I am looking for the Python equivalent of R's mboost package ( [mboost](https://github.com/boost-R/mboost) ).

Would that be xgboost?

Comment: is this what you mean: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html

Comment: Maybe, but I am not sure as the functionality of mboost is not completely clear to me.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on your use case. What is your problem (and why did mboost stand out to you)?